# Sequelize: Get records after updatedAt date

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

How do I search based on `updatedAt` column.  I would like all the records in ascending order after a `date`.

```
var date = "2016-06-18 05:18:27"

Person.findAll({
        where: {
            updatedAt: `> date`  //greater than this date?
        },
        orderBy: '`group` DESC'

    }).then((people) => {

    })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [range operator](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#range-operators) `$gt` to specify an `updatedAt` that is greater than a given `Date`. To [order the results](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#ordering) pass an array of elements, in this case it should be an array with the column as the first element and the direction as the second, for example `[['column', 'DESC']]`.

```js
var date = '2016-06-18 05:18:27';
var myDate = new Date(date);

Person.findAll({
    where: {
        updatedAt: {
            $gt: myDate,
        },
    },
    orderBy: [['group', 'DESC']],
}).then((people) => {
    // results are here
});
```